# cookies not stored after publish on IIS7 server

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, cookies

I get an issue when I want to get cookies on the client

I use

- nodejs 14.16.1
- orchardcore (for openid)
- IIS7
- VueJS

after I publish the project on the server I get a problem when it stores cookies on the client browser.

here are a few things I've tried:

1. change cookies to secure=true and sameSite=none
2. Adding Cors Credentials
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   and
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
3. Setting IIS web.config

```html
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="Use only secure cookies" preCondition="Unsecured cookie">
  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; secure" />
  </rule>
<preConditions>
<preCondition name="Unsecured cookie">
<add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="." />
<add input="{RESPONSE_SET_COOKIE}" pattern="; secure" negate="true" />
</preCondition>
</preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

[The result of the response from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4OmD.png)

[Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nosPZ.png)

[Request Cookie and Response Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt6iW.png)

then on the application page->cookies

[image page application->cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF7ak.png)

I don't see any flags on the cookie, so I think it's working properly

API when getting and redirecting cookies

```js
  res.cookie('auth_token', tokenSet.access_token,{
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
      httpOnly: false
  })
  res.cookie('refresh_token', tokenSet.refresh_token, {
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
    path: '/',
      httpOnly: false
  })

  if (checkUser == null) {
    return res.redirect(process.env.frontend_optional_registration_root)
  } else {
    res.cookie('role', checkUser.role, {
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
    path: '/',
      httpOnly: false
    })
    return res.redirect(process.env.frontend_root)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation I have encountered: if there is a difference in the domain/server name, the cookie will not be visible. Be sure to use the same domain and name to access the server as the server thinks the domain and name are the same.

For example, we had a server installed as domain1 but accessed it using only domain. When we accessed the server connecting directly to domain1, the cookie was visible.